# Move Message to another mail folder with graphApi PageIterator

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I created a Graph API in Azure AD, with required Application API permissions. I'd like to move diffent user's old messages to another folder to archive them.

When I try to move `Message` within `PageIterator` loop, only the first paged results moved to another `MailFolder`. However when I `Copy` these items everything is working fine.

```
//===========================
//Copy or move Message items between specified user's folder
//===========================
var msgList = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Models.Message>();
var messagePageIterator = PageIterator<Microsoft.Graph.Models.Message,
MessageCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(graphClient, resultInbox,
  (msg) =>
  {
    msgList.Add(msg);
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(msg.ReceivedDateTime.ToString() + " - " + msg.Subject);
    var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.Messages.Item.Move.MovePostRequestBody // <- Don't iterate to next page
    //var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.Messages.Item.Copy.CopyPostRequestBody // <- This working fine
    {
       DestinationId = MailFolderArhiveInbox.Id, // or to: "deleteditems",
    };
    var result1 = graphClient.Users[ArchiveUser.Id].Messages[msg.Id].Move.PostAsync(requestBody); // <- Don't iterate to next page
    //var result1 = graphClient.Users[ArchiveUser.Id].Messages[msg.Id].Copy.PostAsync(requestBody); // <- This working fine
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(msgList.Count.ToString() + ". COPY: " + 
    result1.Result.ReceivedDateTime.ToString() + " - " + result1.Result.Subject);
    return true;
  },
  (req) =>
  {
    // Re-add the header to subsequent requests
    req.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type=\"text\"");
    return req;
  });
  //await messagePageIterator.IterateAsync(_canceller.Token);
await messagePageIterator.IterateAsync();
```

I have the items in the collection.
[image: First page contains 10 items and the total itemcount is 14.]

The email filter is working fine. I have the items in my `MessageCollectionResponse` (`resultInbox` in my code):

```
//===========================
//Get items from inbox folder
//===========================
var resultInbox = await graphClient.Users[ArchiveUser.Id].MailFolders[mailFolderInbox.Id].Messages.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "sender", "subject", "receivedDateTime", "toRecipients" };
  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"receivedDateTime le {archiveDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}";
  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { "receivedDateTime" };
  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true;
  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 10;
  requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type=\"text\"");
  //requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");
});
```

Even though I tried to enter a number smaller or larger than the default 10 to the `.Top` parameter, the `Move` command still made the first `Value.Count` piece. If I run it with the `.Copy` command (lines are commented in the code), it does it properly, it goes through all the pages.

I'm using Microsoft.Graph 5.19.

Comment: Not sure, but sounds to be the common _foreach_ problem where you change the collection while iterating. Due to the movement you change the content of the inbox, making the continuation token invalid. Maybe it works better to simply redo requesting the first e.g. 100 items after archiving, which should return the next elements, cause the old ones are already moved.